# What can cause SQLite Error code 778 on Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I use ACRA for error reporting and in the last 30 days I got 6 (I have 10's of thousands of users) crash reports that are similar to this:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 778)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:931)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.replaceOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1411)
 :
```

These happen at various parts of my app.  All the devices are Samsung devices which run Android 4.1.2.  I suspect a Samsung bug, but it there anything I can do to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting an IllegalStateException after reading an sqlite row with 4.1.2 that was previously written without error.  This only happens with certain column values.  Most column values work fine.  In addition, I can take the same DB and read it fine on Android 2.3 as well as a version of sqlite on the pc.  Furthermore, I installed an sqlite browser (aSQLiteManager) on the 4.1.2 device and it crashes trying to read that table.  I can only assume that this is a bug in the version of sqlite (3.7.11) that is deployed with 4.1.2.  I will report this to the sqlite team.

Comment: Good info.  Did you noticed what in particular about the column value causes the crash?

Comment: No, I have not figured that out.  For now I am just catching the exception that it causes and notifying the user of my app that this bug exists.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and it was caused by file descriptor open limit. This limit can be reached by the extensive usage of open files, sockets or cursors. Also, if you have a leak from one of these resources, this error can occurs in your application after some continuous usage.

Comment: Probably a Samsung bug.  Every one of the crash reports are from Samsung devices -- no other brand has ever produced a repor.t

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to this [SQLite bug](http://www.sqlite.org/src/tkthistory/df678d738a) afflicting Android 4.2.2 and 4.2.1 .

You can see that the [Android fix](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sqlite.git/+/6ab557bdc070f11db30ede0696888efd19800475%5E!/) has been included in Android version 4.3 and is related to the AUTO_VACUUM SQLite option which is enabled by default on android.

You can change AUTO_VACUUM value for your database but be careful and read the [AUTO_VACUUM documentation page](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) before to be sure that the solution fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found that at least some of the tests `(ExtensionWebstorePrivateApiTest.AppInstallBubble` for example) succeed on a `dev image` but fail on a `test image`. This is even when running them via an `sshfs mounted directory` (no autotest involved). I see an error on the screen about an invalid profile and this:

```
[10375:10375:0702/172634:2214463961:ERROR:nss_util.cc(88)] Failed to create /home/chronos/user/.pki/nssdb directory.
[10375:10375:0702/172634:2214497333:ERROR:nss_util.cc(588)] Error opening persistent database (configDir='sql:' tokenDescription='Real NSS database'): NSS error code: -8192
[10375:10406:0702/172634:2214908084:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 778, errno 0: disk I/O error
[10375:10406:0702/172634:2214908549:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: no such table: meta
[10375:10384:0702/172634:2214913640:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 778, errno 0: disk I/O error
[10375:10384:0702/172634:2214913831:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: no such table: meta
[10375:10406:0702/172634:2214913926:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: SQL logic error or missing database
[10375:10384:0702/172634:2214914378:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: no such table: meta
[10375:10384:0702/172634:2214914415:ERROR:keyword_table.cc(536)] Can't write default search id backup.
[10375:10384:0702/172634:2214914432:ERROR:keyword_table.cc(465)] Failed to update default search id backup.
[10375:10384:0702/172634:2214914475:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: SQL logic error or missing database
[10375:10384:0702/172634:2214914497:ERROR:web_data_service.cc(657)] Cannot initialize the web database: 1
[10375:10375:0702/172635:2215119305:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(495)] Failed to call method: org.bluez.Manager.DefaultAdapter: object_path= /: org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter
[10375:10384:0702/172639:2219896500:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 778, errno 0: disk I/O error
[10375:10384:0702/172639:2219896877:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: no such table: meta
[10375:10384:0702/172639:2219896943:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: SQL logic error or missing database
[10375:10384:0702/172639:2219898265:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 778, errno 0: disk I/O error
[10375:10384:0702/172639:2219898567:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: no such table: meta
[10375:10384:0702/172639:2219898658:ERROR:diagnostic_error_delegate.h(31)] sqlite error 1, errno 0: SQL logic error or missing database
[0702/172716:ERROR:test_launcher.cc(386)] Test timeout (45000 ms) exceeded for ExtensionWebstorePrivateApiTest.AppInstallBubble
```

`BUGFIX：SQLITE 4.4.1` has fixed the bug indicating by `error code 778`, which is caused by `disk reading fault`, which is actually recoverable internally by the `db engine` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [official Sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr_write). It seems to be a hardware exception, if it cannot be reproduced, maybe we can try to ignore this problem?

[(778) SQLITE_IOERR_WRITE](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr_write)

> The SQLITE_IOERR_WRITE error code is an
> extended error code for SQLITE_IOERR indicating an I/O error in the
> VFS layer while trying to write into a file on disk. This error might
> result from a hardware malfunction or because a filesystem came
> unmounted while the file was open. This error should not occur if the
> filesystem is full as there is a separate error code (SQLITE_FULL) for
> that purpose.